# Several updates on the same view Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, routes

In a setup process I want to:

1. select langs of the application (1 or more) ...
2. Update the DB
3. Select the default language
4. Update again the DB...

**For this i created 3 routes.**

```
Route::get('/home/setup', 'BackOffice\FirstconnectionController@initLang');
Route::patch('/home/setup', 'BackOffice\FirstconnectionController@initLangUpdate')->name('setup.setLang');
Route::patch('/home/setup', 'BackOffice\FirstconnectionController@setDefaultLang')->name('setup.setDefaultLang');
```

- The first is the home page where i make eloquent requests
- The second route display the list of languages
- The third route displays the list of languages which are published ...

Here is my view :

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
{{-- IF NO LANGS ARE PUBLISHED I CAN CHOOSE HERE --}}
@if ($langsCount == 0)
    {!!  Form::model($langs, [
            'method' => 'PATCH',
            'route' => 'setup.setLang'
        ])
    !!}
    @foreach($langs as $lang)
        <div class="form-group">
            {{--<label class="col-md-4">  {{ $lang->langname }} </label>--}}
            {{--<input id="{{ $lang->langisocode }}" type="checkbox">--}}

            {!! Form::label($lang->langname,  $lang->langname ) !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox( 'lang[]', $lang->id ) !!}
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}

{{-- NOW I SELECT DEFAULT LANGUAGE... --}}
@else
    {!!  Form::model($langs, [
            'method' => 'PATCH',
            'route' => 'setup.setDefaultLang'
        ])
    !!}

    @foreach($pubLangs as $pubLang)
        {!! Form::label($pubLang->langname,  $pubLang->langname ) !!}
        {!! Form::radio( 'lang', $pubLang->id ) !!}
        <br>
    @endforeach
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endif
```

**Here is my controller :**

```
// I display the info here
public function initLang()
{

    $langs = Lang::onlyTrashed()->get();
    $langsCount = Lang::count();
    $pubLangs = Lang::all();

    return view('admin.firstConnection', compact('langs', 'langsCount', 'pubLangs'));
}

public function initLangUpdate(Request $request) {
    $request = $request->input('lang');
    foreach ($request as $entry) {
        Lang::withTrashed()->find($entry)->restore();
    }
    return redirect('admin/home/setup')->with('success', 'OK');
}

public function setDefaultLang(Request $request) {
    $request = $request->input('lang');
    return $request;
}
```

I will update the setDefaultLang after ... 
I have this error message : 
Route [setup.setLang] not defined

Comment: You can't have 2 routes with the same method and the same Uri but different names, so the second route is overwriting the name of the first one.

Comment: I have 2 routes on the same URL but methods and names are different.. In fact i want to stay on the same URL ...

Comment: The method, as in the http verb "patch" is the same for both, as is the Uri, how will the server know which controller method to call if both the Uri and the verb are the same? Route names are just a convenience.

Comment: finally i will use another URL ... i'll manage it this way ) thanks for your help